# Why can't I approve edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

I'm a little surprised to find today that suggested edits I approve don't automatically go through. I used the suggested edits queue to [approve an edit to this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57710/1925), only to find that it still doesn't show and the post as the `edit(1)` thing showing a pending edit. Opening this shows a modal action box with this message:

> You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.

As a 20k+ user, I can edit posts and have them go through immediately. I used to be able to approve suggested edits as well.

Is this feature broken or did something change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As with most odd cases on Stack Exchange, this is SO's fault. SO has always required two people to approve edits; everywhere else required one. They continued to [have problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) with [terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/470439) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/426490) [getting](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/278108) [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/202749), so in October SO's requirements were increased so [three votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/145982) are needed, and at the same time all the other sites on the network, including us, were bumped up to two votes

The theory is that making your own edit is easier than reviewing somebody else's. People seem to have a habit of glancing at an edit and thinking "that seems not horrifying", and clicking Approve, when that edit wasn't actually very good and they never would've made it themselves. Requiring multiple reviewers hopefully avoids that, although I don't really think we had that problem here to begin with

Comment: Grrr-a-humbug. I'm going to [suggest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157801/145951) that even if 2 votes are required now, 10k+ users reviews should be trusted a little more on 2.0 sites like ours where reviews take longer to come in.